# how do I load the UIpicker on page load in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, uipickerview

I have two pickers and I want picker1 to be show by default when the page first loads and also when user touches the UI. I want to show in both ways for picker1.

```
func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
    if pickerView == picker1 {
        return 1
    } else {
        return 2
    }
}

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
    var tempCount = 0
    if pickerView == picker1 {
        tempCount = pickerData.count
    } else {
    }
    return tempCount
}

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
    var tempPickerData = ""
    if pickerView == picker1 {
        tempPickerData = pickerData[row]
    } else {
    }
    return tempPickerData
}

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
    if pickerView == picker1 {
        selected = pickerData[row]
    } else {

    }
}
```

Comment: so whats the issue ?

Comment: @jawadali I want to show picker 1 when the page loads..right now it will load only if I tap that button. I want to display it in page load too.

Comment: Once your view (UITextField?) appears on screen, call `becomeFirstResponder()` on it.